# Angular: change form dynamically as per the selection

Tags: angularjs

I am quite new to Angular. I would like to change form dynamically as per the selection from select box.

```
<form name="register" method="post" id="register" role="form" ng-submit="registerForm()">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : erroractype }">    
        <select id="actype" name="actype" class=" selector form-control" ng-model="formData.actype" required="required"> 
           <option value="" selected="selected" >I am</option>
          <option value="1"> Student</option>
          <option value="2"> Teacher</option>
          <option value="3"> School</option>
          </select>
<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorName" class="ng-cloak">{{ erroractype }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorFname }">

<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" title="Please Enter Your First Name" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.Fname">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorFname" class="ng-cloak">{{errorFname}}</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorLname }">
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" title="Please Enter Your Last Name" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.Lname">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorLname" class="ng-cloak">{{ errorLname }}</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorEmail1 }">
<input type="email" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" title="Please Enter Your Valid Email" required="required" ng-model="formData.Email1">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorEmail1" class="ng-cloak">{{ errorEmail1 }}</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorPassword1 }">
<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Password" title="Please enter AlphaNumeric value" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.Password1">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorPassword1" class="ng-cloak">{{ errorPassword1 }}</div>
{{ errorPassword1 }}
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errormobile }">
    <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number (+1)" title="Please Enter Your Contact Number without Coutry Code." class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.mobile">
    <div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errormobile" class="ng-cloak">{{ errormobile }}</div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name="btn-register" id="btn-register" required="required">Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

As you can see three types of registration can be done as per the selection in select box. Student, Teacher and School.

For Student and Teacher form is looking fine. They would have first name & last name. But when people select school that time first name last name looks ugly. It should be only school with single textbox.

So, basically I want whenever school get selected lastname text box get hidden and First Name textbox become Name of School. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked at [ng-select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)? You could use the model bound to this select statement to change the display property of your text box and also change the text box name.

Comment: any example will help me a lot. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I came up with something like this. When You'll select the option `One` you'll see the changes you require. Here is a link to the working example: http://codepen.io/ayushgp/pen/BWMjgG

HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="test">
    <select name="number" ng-model="type">
      <option value="0" selected>--Select an option--</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      {{type == 1 ? 'Name of school' : 'First Name'}}:   <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div ng-style="{'display':type==1?'none':'block'}">
      Last name: <input type="text" />
    </div>    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158782/angular-ng-cloak-not-working have a look into this. Might be you can help.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine swap `none` and `block`