# ng-cloak not working in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to remove `{{ }}` from my website. Basically it came if angular didn't load. So, I checked SO and found some answer to use `ng-cloak`. I tried that but I can still see `{{ }}`. I added the CSS code below in a CSS file as well as locally on the page.

**CSS**

```
.ng-cloak {
      display: none !important; 
}
```

Here is the form.

```
<form name="register" method="post" id="register" role="form" ng-submit="registerForm()">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : erroractype }">    
        <select id="actype" name="actype" class=" selector form-control" ng-model="formData.actype" required="required"> 
           <option value="" selected="selected" >I am</option>
          <option value="1"> Student</option>
          <option value="2"> Teacher</option>
          <option value="3"> School</option>
          </select>
<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorName" class="ng-cloak">{{ erroractype }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorFname }">

<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" title="Please Enter Your First Name" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.Fname">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorFname" class="ng-cloak">{{errorFname}}</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorLname }">
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" title="Please Enter Your Last Name" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.Lname">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorLname" class="ng-cloak">{{ errorLname }}</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorEmail1 }">
<input type="email" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" title="Please Enter Your Valid Email" required="required" ng-model="formData.Email1">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorEmail1" class="ng-cloak">{{ errorEmail1 }}</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorPassword1 }">
<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Password" title="Please enter AlphaNumeric value" class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.Password1">
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorPassword1" class="ng-cloak">{{ errorPassword1 }}</div>
{{ errorPassword1 }}
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errormobile }">
    <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number (+1)" title="Please Enter Your Contact Number without Coutry Code." class="form-control input-sm textbox1" required="required" ng-model="formData.mobile">
    <div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errormobile" class="ng-cloak">{{ errormobile }}</div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name="btn-register" id="btn-register" required="required">Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Any advice as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by if happens if angular didn't load?

Comment: can you show an example of what's being displayed?

Comment: Like i said when page load for fraction of second it is showing {{ errorFname }} and all the codes inside {{ }}

Comment: have you tried using ng-if instead of ng-show?

Answer (score 1):

Apply `ng-cloak` at the root level, where you mentioned your `ng-app` directive. (html tag probably), further I would suggest to completely avoid `ng-cloak` , and start using `ng-bind`. It will solve your problem of flickering of `{{}} interpolation operator`

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `ng-cloak` to individual elements. Applying it to the root tag will also solve your problem but it might cause other problems. Quoted from [ngCloak doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak#!):

> The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple `ngCloak` directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

Also keep the following in mind:

> For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must be included in the external stylesheet of the application.

Comment: angular is added in head section. Also custom style also added in head section. You can see ng-cloak is added in individual elements.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine You're still seeing the braces?

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Strange. Because this is just basic HTML and CSS, create a CSS class and apply it to bunch of tags. Is your css placed before the angular script as loading the angular script might delay the styles from being applied?

Comment: yes it is before angular script. Just after angular.js.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine I meant the angular.js only. Try placing it before that.

Comment: Tried that as well. No success. Same issue.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine can't think of anything else and can't reproduce this. Won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, that was a silly mistake.

```
<div class = "alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorEmail1" class="ng-cloak">{{ errorEmail1 }}</div>
```

Needs to change like this.

```
<div class = "alert alert-danger ng-cloak" ng-show="errorEmail1" >{{ errorEmail1 }}</div>
```

It was really silly. A very basic one. I hope someone will come across these kinds of funny situation.